# Django 1.6: Matching query does not exist

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu, get

I'm trying to implement a dropdown form which filters objects depending on the selection from the dropdown. I don't have any issues doing that but it gives me an error when nothing is selected and clicked submit. I want it to not filter anything and just give the entire list of the objects but i get the following error `Specialization matching query does not exist` on line

```
spec = Specialization.objects.get(name = s_name)
```

Here is the template where I've the form

```
<form action="/doclistings/" method="GET" >
        <select class="form-control" id="selection" name="selection">
          <option><b>Choose a Speciality...</b></option>
          {% for value, text in form.selection.field.choices %}
            <option name="choicemade" value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
          <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
        </select>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="submit" id="ss-submit">Find Doctors</button>
        </span>
      </form>
```

here is the form

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ('Dermatologist', 'Dermatologist'),
    ('Dentist', 'Dentist'),
    ('Orthopedist', 'Orthopedist'),
    ('Pediatrician', 'Pediatrician'),
)

class DropdownSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES, widget = forms.Select, required = False)
    genderselect = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget= forms.Select, required = False)
```

here is the view that's rendering the dropdown form

```
def index(request):
    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': "Home"})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            selection = form.cleaned_data['selection']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/doclistings')
    else:
        form = DropdownSelectionForm()

    return render(request, 'meddy1/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the view that's rendering the objects based on the selection

```
def doclistings(request):
    d = getVariables(request)
    if request.method == "GET":

        s_name = request.GET['selection']

        if s_name == "":
            doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('-netlikes')

        else:
            spec = Specialization.objects.get(name = s_name)
            doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(specialization = spec).order_by('-netlikes')

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/doclistings')


    d['doctors'] = doctors
    return render_to_response('meddy1/doclistings.html',d)
```

Comment: Please show code of your form

Comment: I've added the form code above

Comment: Please show MY_CHOICES

Comment: hm... Try to add debug and look at s_name variable in your view or just print it and make sure that Specialization with such name exists. If all is ok, please write all traceback of error and s_name value.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should use the QueryDict methods as this:

```
s_name = request.GET.get('selection', None)
if not s_name:
    #if s_name is None
    #...
```

That way it will fallback correctly if s_name is not present.